# Why are the source and header files modified, but the makefile is not recompiled

Tags: c, makefile

I encountered a problem about makefile, I modified my 2 source files link_ec.c and link_cloud.c, and 2 head files link_ec.h and link_cloud.h, but makefile is not recompiled. Is there a problem with where it was written?

my makefile as follows:

```
LIB_FOR_JSON          = ./lib/json_lib/*
LIB_FOR_MQTT          = ./lib/mqtt_lib/*


SRC_DIR               = ./src
OUTPUT_DIR            = ./output
SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR     = /usr/local/lib

TARGET    = linkCloudApp
RM        = rm -rf 
MV        = mv 
CP        = cp -r
LDCONFIG  = ldconfig

#### compile comment #####  
COMPILE                    = aarch64-linux-gnu-
CC                         = $(COMPILE)gcc
STRIP                      = $(COMPILE)strip
LD                         = $(COMPILE)ld

COMPILE_OPTION             = -O2 -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wswitch -Wuninitialized  \
                             -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare -Wshadow
#COMPILE_OPTION_DEBUG       = -gdwarf-2 -g 

COMPILE_ALL_OPTION         += $(COMPILE_OPTION) $(COMPILE_OPTION_DEBUG)

LINK_OPTION                 =  -lpaho-mqtt3a -ljson-c  -lm  -lpthread -lz

OBJS_MAIN                  = main.o
OBJS_LINK_EC               = link_ec.o
OBJS_LINK_CLOUD            = link_cloud.o


OBJS = $(OBJS_MAIN) $(OBJS_LINK_EC) $(OBJS_LINK_CLOUD)

                         
$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)  $(OBJS)  $(LINK_OPTION)
    $(STRIP) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)


$(OBJS_MAIN):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_LINK_EC):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/link_ec.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_LINK_CLOUD):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/link_cloud.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)



    
.PHONY:clean copylib
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/* $(OBJS)
copylib:
    $(CP) $(LIB_FOR_MQTT) $(SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR)/
    $(CP) $(LIB_FOR_JSON) $(SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR)/
    $(LDCONFIG)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object file recipes don't have any dependencies associated with them, so they won't get built unless you specify them explicitly.

Add the .c files to the dependency lists:

```
$(OBJS_MAIN): $(SRC_DIR)/main.c
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_LINK_EC): $(SRC_DIR)/link_ec.c
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/link_ec.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_LINK_CLOUD): $(SRC_DIR)/link_cloud.c
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/link_cloud.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
```

Or you could make a single generic target for all of your .o files:

```
%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION) -c $<
```